# Run APK file in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have install Eclipse, SDK and ADT in my machine.

Can anyone assist me how can I run .apk sample files in Eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to install your building app or want to run any external app? If you have app and want to run its apk on emulator then, click the run button at the top. And, if you want to run any other external apk then go through `adb install myapkfilename.apk`

Comment: I have download a sample APK file Sudoku.apk, and now I want to run it in Eclipse. I have create a AVD but I don't know how I can select the Sudoku.apk file so I can test and run them?

Comment: You ofcourse cannot open the .apk file in your eclipse IDE. You need to install it on emulator as like we install it on our devices. Go to your Command Prompt, type `adb install Sudoku.apk` and it will install it on your emulator. (Remember, load the adb to your path variables and change your directory location where you have already placed the Sudoku.apk)

Comment: How to go to adb install Soduko.apk in Eclipse?

Ok thanks I will try on that..

Comment: Not in eclipse, by your command prompt. Goto Run -> Cmd. now type `adb install Sudoku.apk`

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try.

And do we able to see the source code for this Soduko.apk? If so, How?

Comment: It is the compiled form of the application. I don't think that you can see the source code behind it ofcourse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ofcourse cannot open the .apk file in your eclipse IDE. You need to install it on emulator as like we install it on our devices.

Go to your Command Prompt, type

`adb install Sudoku.apk` and it will install it on your emulator. (**Remember, load the adb to your path variables and change your directory location where you have already placed the Sudoku.apk**)

Comment: Thanks, I now able to see the app running in the Emulator. Can I open and see the source code of the Soduko.apk file? If so, how I can do that?

Comment: I don't think that you can see the source code behind the compiled .apk.

Comment: So there is no way I could see the source code behind the .apk file??

Comment: No, I don't think so because this is the compiled form of our application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an emulator using the Android Virtual Device Manager.  Then when you run it as an android application it will launch the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html

Should cover what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can push a file in emulator by Eclips( and you device that connected to eclips)

1-in device tab select your emulated phone and start it

2-pushing your apk file in file explorer tab by clicckig on PUSH A FILE

It Works.